# Error while uploading code to ESP8266 through Arduino Mega 2560

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-ide, esp8266, uploading, wireless

I am sorry for posting this question for the nth time but I am still not able to find a solution for this error.

I am trying to upload the WiFiScan(Arduino IDE example program)program code to ESP8266 using Arduino Mega 2560. I followed the procedure given [here](https://diyhacking.com/esp8266-tutorial/). And I tried uploading it with "Generic ESP8266 Module" and "Adafruit HUZZAH ESP8266" selected as the Board. But I am still getting the following error.

```
trying to connect
  espcomm_send_command: sending command header
  espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
```

Edited to add:
[image]

**Connections-**

**ESP8266 - Arduino Mega2560**

Tx - Tx1(Pin 18)

Rx - Rx1(Pin 19)

Gnd - Gnd

Vcc - 3.3V (Directly from Arduino's 3.3V pin)

CH_PD - 3.3V (Directly from Arduino's 3.3V pin)

GPIO0 - Push button K2 (refer photo)

RST - Push button K1

While pressing the K2 button(Flash button - GPIO0), I clicked the K1 button(Reset button - RST) and then released K2. According to the document, this should bring the ESP8266 to flash mode. Now when I upload the code, it throws the above error.

Comment: That tutorial doesn't have anything to do with an Arduino Mega and you didn't tell us how you wired it. We can only guess what is wrong.

Comment: Add a photo clearly showing your devices and wiring and you might get a better response.

Comment: As suggested, I've included the connection details in the question. @gre_gor, Squats

Comment: tx to tx and rx to rx ??? have you tried the obvious? tx to rx and rx to tx, seeing as that's how serial connections work

Answer (score 1):

After googling for several hours, I was able to figure out the reason. Thanks to this [link](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/1207). Transferring data to ESP8266 with Arduino acting as USB to Serial converter did not work. Using a USB to TTL converter, and following this [link](https://diyhacking.com/esp8266-tutorial/) you can easily transfer data to ESP8266.

Comment: My Arduino Mega worked as a USB to Serial converter just fine...

Comment: @Fusseldieb could you please tell me how you uploaded data using Arduino Mega?

Comment: I just plugged TX to TX, RX to RX, GND to GND and shorted RST to GND, causing the Arduino to loop continuously on reset. I also chosen "Tools" -> "Programmer" -> "Arduino as ISP". Then I uploaded the sketch just fine.

Comment: `I just plugged TX to TX, RX to RX` - no you didn't

Comment: Why do I see so many people today with the same Tx-Tx Rx-Rx problem.  It's like there was something in the weather today.  Think of it this way, when you have a conversation with someone, do you talk into their mouth and listen to their ears?